# Issue with signup and signin in django

Tags: django

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout

####################################################

class Main(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'emnosys/main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['css_file'] = 'styles.css'
        return context

###################################################



def Registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password1 = request.POST['password1']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, emnail, password1)
        myuser.save()

        return redirect('signin')
    return render(request, "emnosys/registration.html")

###############################################

def signin(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password1 = request.POST['pass1']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "authentication/index.html")
        else:
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, "emnosys/signin.html")

################################################

def signout(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('home')
```

This is my urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import Main


urlpatterns = [
    path('', Main.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('registration/', views.Registration, name='registration'),
    path('signin/', views.signin, name='signin'),
    path('signout/', views.signout, name='signout'),
]
```

this is my registration.html

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/emnosys/css/styles-registration.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div class="login">
            <h3>Registration</h3>

            <form action="/signup" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="write username">
                <br>
                <label for="">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="username" placeholder="write email">
                <br>
                <label for="">Password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password1" name="username" placeholder="write password">
                <br>
                <label for="">Confirm your password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password2" name="username" placeholder="confirm your password">
                <br>
                <button type="sumbit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="waves">
            <img src="../../static/emnosys/images/waves.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

this is my login(signin).html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/emnosys/css/styles-login.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div class="login">
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <div class="username">
                    <input type="text" id="login" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off">
                    <label for="#login" id="label1">Username</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="password">
                    <input type="password" id="password" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off">
                    <label for="#password" id="label2">Password</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="foot">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="remember-me">
                    <label for="#register-link">Remember me</label>
                    <a href="registration.html" id="register-link">Registration</a>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit--button">
                    Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="waves">
                <img src="../../static/emnosys/images/waves.png" alt="">
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I write all data on registration page, press button,

After it i can see text in terminal

[07/Nov/2023 16:50:37] "GET /registration/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=eOYzmvnkKHCBC13PTvIKoUCegTcwTjw1danUrjGXWIqV
nyy5tnnMNcX1Cw2N0QeS&username=parrot&username=parrot%40gmail.com&username=Qwe123&username=Qwe123 HTTP/1.1"
200 1495

And there is no new users in admin panel

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help

I expect that after writing data in registration.html and signin in login.html i will see new user in admin panel

Comment: checkout my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside **registeration.html** you use a from inside a form

so change your registeration.html:-

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/emnosys/css/styles-registration.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="login">
            <h3>Registration</h3>

            <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="write username">
                <br>
                <label for="">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="write email">
                <br>
                <label for="">Password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="write password">
                <br>
                <label for="">Confirm your password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="confirm your password">
                <br>
                <button type="sumbit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="waves">
            <img src="../../static/emnosys/images/waves.png" alt="">
        </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

and your login(signin).html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/emnosys/css/styles-login.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="login">
                <h3>Login</h3>
                <div class="username">
                    <input type="text" id="login" name="username" placeholder=" " autocomplete="off">
                    <label for="#login" id="label1">Username</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="password">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="pass1"  placeholder=" " autocomplete="off">
                    <label for="#password" id="label2">Password</label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="foot">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="" id="remember-me">
                    <label for="#register-link">Remember me</label>
                    <a href="registration.html" id="register-link">Registration</a>
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <button type="submit" id="submit--button">
                    Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="waves">
                <img src="../../static/emnosys/images/waves.png" alt="">
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The primary reason for not saving new user data in the database is due to the fact that your form is making a GET request to the server. Remember that you have logic in your code that checks for `if request.method == "POST"`. This is why the create_user command is not working as expected.

A possible solution would involve fixing your `registration.html` file. In that file, there is a form nested within another form. According to HTML theory, when you submit something within a form that is nested, it should be submitted to the parent form. Therefore, your registration.html file should be structured as follows:

registeration.html

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/emnosys/css/styles-registration.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="login">
            <h3>Registration</h3>

            <form action="/signup" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="write username">
                <br>
                <label for="">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="username" placeholder="write email">
                <br>
                <label for="">Password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password1" name="username" placeholder="write password">
                <br>
                <label for="">Confirm your password</label>
                <input type="text" id="password2" name="username" placeholder="confirm your password">
                <br>
                <button type="sumbit">Sign Up</button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="waves">
            <img src="../../static/emnosys/images/waves.png" alt="">
        </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

In this solution, I removed the first `<form>` tag, which should now ensure that the POST request is sent to your view as intended. For your login page you should do exactly the same to make it working.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
<form action="/signup" method="post">
```

try this:

```
<form action="{% url 'registration' %}" method="post">
```

Comment: he doesnt even have method defined; main issue. The form action empty is fine if it's `POST`ing to the same page.